# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new in iphone, I'm trying to open a view when pressing a button,
in my class "ReaderViewController" I wrote the following code:

```
- (void)tappedInToolbar:(ReaderMainToolbar *)toolbar emailButton:(UIButton *)button
{
#ifdef DEBUGX
NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
#endif

#if (READER_ENABLE_MAIL == TRUE) // Option

instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchView"];

if (printInteraction != nil) [printInteraction dismissAnimated:NO]; // Dismiss

SearchViewController *searchController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchView"];


searchController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
searchController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

[self presentModalViewController:searchController animated:YES];


[searchController release];


#endif // end of READER_ENABLE_MAIL Option
}
```

I want when to open the view of this controller "SearchViewController" and in storyboard I gave the view of SearchViewController its identifier name "searchView"
but when I run, it gives me the following Exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:    'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <ReaderViewController: 0x6864930>.'
```

Any Help ??
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Assuming you're **absolutely** sure the identifiers are exact matches in spelling and capitalization, try putting `NSLog(@"Storyboard: %@", self.storyboard);` right before you ask it for the `SearchViewController` and see what that says.

Comment: it gives me "null" although I wrote (searchView) in the identifier in storyboard

Comment: So it's saying that your problem is that you don't have `self.storyboard` initialized to a valid storyboard reference.

Answer (score 1):

There's no view controller with the identifier `searchView` in your storyboard, so the instantiation fails and the

```
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
```

method returns nil. Double check your Storyboard setup and also note that identifiers and names are generally case-sensitive, maybe you named your view controller `SearchView` and not `searchView`.

It also may be the case that

```
self.storyboard
```

itself isn't properly initialized or instantiated, and thus is nil.

**Edit**: so you were creating the storyboard from code, but in fact you weren't. The solution was to manually instantiate UIStoryboard.

As for your own comment, you'd better assign `self.storyboard = Storyboard` or you'll continue getting these errors...

Comment: NSLog(@"Storyboard: %@", self.storyboard); gives me "null" although I wrote (searchView) in the identifier of SearchViewController, Any Suggestions??

Comment: @user1553381 yes, so my 2nd guess is correct and the storyboard is nil. Do you use a XIB/NIB file? Or are you creating the storyboard programmatically?

Comment: I solved this issue, I used the following code `NSString *stbName = [[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"];
    
    UIStoryboard *Mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:stbName bundle:nil];
    
    SearchViewController *searchController = [Mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchView"];
    
        
    [self presentModalViewController:searchController animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `self.storyboard` is `nil`.  This means every message you are passing to it results in `nil` also.

Comment: then what is the solution for it...?